# How to get requester port on aiohttp.web

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, aiohttp

I have a `funtion` to get ip address of requester.

```
async def remote(self,request):
    print(request.remote)
    return web.Response(text=str(request.remote), status=200)
```

I need to get the port of requester. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be found in [official doc](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html?highlight=peername#aiohttp.web.BaseRequest.transport):

```
peername = request.transport.get_extra_info('peername')
if peername is not None:
    host, port = peername
```